# How to Iterate Over Objects to Determine Their Variable Content Depending on How Many Objects There Are in the Class?

Tags: java, loops, variables, object, constructor

I am VERY NEW to Java. I don't even know if I am asking the correct question, however I need help.

So I am trying to set an object's variables depending on what the user inputs. However, I am trying to make my code more efficient (by re-using methods) and this is my problem:

```
if (Store.product1.productName.equals("")){
    Store.product1.setProductName(inputProduct);
    Store.product1.setProductDemandRate(productDR);
    Store.product1.setProductSetupCost(productSC);
    Store.product1.setProductUnitCost(productUC);
    Store.product1.setProductInventoryCost(productIC);
    Store.product1.setProductSellingCost(productSP);
    System.out.println(System.lineSeparator() + "Product " + inputWithCap + " Added Successfully. Returning to Main-Menu" + System.lineSeparator());
    displayMenu();
}
```

So if I have 5 products, does that really mean I have to have that large amount of code 5 times? I can't think of a method that would allow me to just shove in some parameters and it'll do the rest :(

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

**NB:** I'm not allowed to use arrays :(

Comment: Create a function with 6 parameters, or 7 if you want to pass `Store.product1` in as well, then call the function whenever you need to.

Comment: Search for Builder pattern in the GoF book or if you have Joshua Bloch's Effective Java (2nd edition) book in hand, look at Item 2.

Comment: @JonnyHenly You know, even though I couldn't figure it out last night. Once I read your comment and actually tried it, I figured it out. So the way I did it was I sent the product as a parameter and then in the method I called the setter methods. Simple. THANKS :)

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need to repeat your code several times. Each time you need a new product you should create one and then add it to the store once the values are set:

```
Product product = new Product(name);
product.setDemandRate(demandRate);
...
store.add(product);
```

The store needs to be able to take as many new products as you need. There are plenty of structures other than arrays that you can use to store them.